# installing pyqt5 for python2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, pip

I run the command

```
pip install pyqt5
```

and I get the following error

```
~$ pip install pyqt5

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

Please note I really need *Python2* `pyqt5` and *not Python3* `pyqt5`, as the program I got is very old.

thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to build pyqt5 for Python2. In [here](https://medium.com/@Lola_Dam/building-pyqt5-for-python-2-on-linux-b054f697b60c) the author faced the same problem and wrote the steps to build it for Python2 on Linux.